# What are the practical reasons for have a high or low finesse value for a laser?

Tags: optics, temperature, laser, laser-cavity

I was just wondering if someone could expand on what finesse of a laser cavity is, from my lecture notes I know how one would calculate it via the equation:

$$F=\frac{4R}{(1-R)^2}$$

where $R$ is the reflection coefficient but what is the use of finesse in terms of the practical application? Does a laser has to have a high finesse, low finesse, or are there situations where a high finesse is more practical compared to a low finesse.

Comment: Unclear what this is about. Subject or what?

Comment: Sorry, copied in an old title from notes I was making on another subject. My apologies

Comment: High finesse is good for metrology, e.g.  determining atomic spectra. Low finesse, within reason, is better for time-dependent things  i.e. telecoms or even simply measuring short events, like dynamics of electron population in solids.